# Fundamental group of adeles

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $k$ be a global field and let $\mathbb{A}_k$ be its adele ring.

What is the etale fundamental group of $\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{A}_k)$?

When is a finite etale cover of $\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{A}_k)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{A}_L)$ for some Galois extension $L$ of $k$?

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{A}_k)$ is not connected, so how do you define its fundamental group?